# I want to make basic real estate script with python

Tags: python, sqlite

Firstly I want to create real estate script so it should have menu. Firstly it'll ask what you want to do in the script.

I created this menu:

```
menu = 0

while menu != 6:
    try:
        answer = str(menu)

        menu = int(input(To buy house press 1\n To sell house press 2  , \n To list your house press 3,  \n for exit press 4 " "\n"))
    except(SyntaxError,NameError):
        print ("Enter correct numbers")
```

I know it's very simple and I need some ideas to improve it. Then I want to create first menu but I am stuck on how to use database correctly. I want to show you second menu because it's more important to me.

Second menu:

```
  if menu == 2:
    cursor=connectdb.cursor()

    def create table():
        cursor.execute(
        CREATE TABLE newhouse(
        m_square INTEGER NOT NULL,
        room_number INTEGER NOT NULL ,
        place INTEGER NOT NULL,
        house_cost INTEGER NOT NULL
        )
        );
        con.close()

        m2 = input ('How many square meters is your home?  ' "\n" )
        room = input ('Enter the number of rooms of your home ' "\n" )
        floor = input ('On which floor is your house? ' "\n")
        price = input ('Enter the sales price of your home  '  )
```

The idea is to get data from user and write from database but I am really stuck here and I'm a beginner. If I pass this part, I'll try the other parts.

Thanks for reading and helping to me :)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @LarryLustig Hey Larry,My que is How can I get this data from user and how can I write to database

Comment: You can write to database with `execute` method. You'll need to spend some time with [the python api  docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute). Spoiler: That "create table" will execute successfully exactly once; it will error on any subsequent call because the table exists. Learn about "IF NOT EXISTS" from the [sqlite doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)